Which syslog RFCs syslog4j support?
I want to use logback syslog4j appender  and interested if it supports RFC 5424
Based on http://www.syslog4j.org/ I see that syslog4j supports both: RFC 3164 and RFC 5424

Syslog4j provides client and server implementations of the BSD Syslog
protocol (RFC 3164) and the Structured Syslog protocol (RFC 5424).

But when I read FAQ I see:

1.1.  What is Syslog4j?

Syslog4j is a pure-Java implementation of the syslog client and server
specification as defined by "The BSD syslog Protocol" (RFC3164) with
additional support for TCP/IP-based syslog, native Unix syslog, and
Unix sockets.

Java applications (web or otherwise) needing to log messages to a syslog
server or Java applications needing to accept syslog messages can use
Syslog4j.


and:

3.3.  So why would I bother using Syslog4j if I already use Log4j?
Syslog4j provides support for protocols other than UDP, which is the
only network protocol supported by the Log4j's SyslogAppender.
The SyslogAppender provided by Log4j is hard-coded to use the standard
syslog port 514 with a maximum message size of 1024 bytes and
currently does not support Structured Syslog messages as per RFC 5424.

So I can't understand if RFC 5424 supported. Could you please clarify?

" currently does not support Structured Syslog messages as per RFC 5424." sounds to me like RFC 5424 is not supported. That said, it seems that SysLog4j is for Log4j 1.x, not Log4j 2.x. Log4j 2.x seems to support RFC 5424 according to this page

@Mark Rotteveel for me too, but another phrase says different from my point of view but I don't know how to check

@Mark Rotteveel do you mean log4j 2.x doesn't use syslog4j appender for syslog integration but uses their own implementation which support RFC 5424 ?

'Syslog4j provides client and server implementations of the BSD Syslog protocol (RFC 3164) and the Structured Syslog protocol (RFC 5424)'.  But what does it mean ?

According to the Log4j2 documentation it does support RFC 5424. Note that the last update on syslog4j was before Log4j2 was created, so it is no wonder that syslog4j does not mention Log4j2. It also seems that the last update for syslog4j was 13 years ago and so I'm wondering whether this would still work with newer Java versions and newer versions of Log4j / Log4j2. The same holds for the logback-syslog appender which had its last updates about 10 years ago.

@Thomas Kläger So you mean that the best option for me is to use log4j2 if I need  RFC 5424 ?

you can try this looks like logback with rfc 5424 and some says log4j2
